# .ExecuteNonQuery() sql asp.net error

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012, executenonquery

This is my first time working with sql and asp.net. I am working on a few examples to ensure I have all the basics I need.  I was walking though a tutorial and where everything should be working just fine, I am getting an .ExecuteNonQuery() Error.  SqlException was unhandled by user code // Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

If you have any pointers, let me know.  I worked the tutorial twice, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here.   -Thanks

.CS Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebSite
{
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Table values('" + txtfName.Text + "','" + txtlName.Text + "','" + txtpNumber.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Your DATA has been submitted";
        txtpNumber.Text = "";
        txtlName.Text = "";
        txtfName.Text = "";
    }
  }
}
```

.aspx File:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="auto-style1">

    <strong>Insert data into Database<br />
    <br />
    </strong>

</div>
    <table align="center" class="auto-style2">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">First Name:</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfName" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Last Name:</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtlName" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Phone Number:</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtpNumber" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" Width="150px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#663300" style="text-align: center" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

SQL Database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
[Id]      INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[fName]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[lName]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[pNumber] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this error message is caused by a single quote present in your input textboxes or by the use of a reserved keyword. Both problems are present in your query. The TABLE word is a [reserved keyword for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) and thus you should encapsulate it with square brackets, while for the possible presence of a single quote in the input text the correct approach is to use [Parameterized Query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [Table] values(@fnam, @lnam, @pNum)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fnam", txtfName.Text );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lnam", txtlName.Text );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pNum", txtpNumber.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

With this approach you shift the work to parse your input text to the framework code and you avoid problems with parsing text and [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Also, I suggest to **NOT USE** a global variable to keep the SqlConnection reference. It is an expensive resource and, if you forget to close and dispose it, you could have a significant impact on the performance and the stability of your application.
For this kind of situations the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is all you really need

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                             ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString));
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [Table] values(@fnam, @lnam, @pNum)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fnam", txtfName.Text );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lnam", txtlName.Text );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pNum", txtpNumber.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Of course remove the global variable and the open in the Page_Load

Comment: +1, but I also belive that you need to make your sql as:`insert into [Table] values....` because the table is actually the name that is used :-/ and is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Yes @Aristos I have added this also, looking for the correct link to add to the answer

Comment: This is the actual error at the first place, but is good to give him this complete answer. The name Table is very basic like the select :) is when you create a table ! Have it and on their question :)...

Comment: @Steve. "_have a global variable to keep the SqlConnection reference_" - really? This is what a connection pool is for. Keeping your own global connection is not considered best practice in most cases. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10116623/1945631, for example

Comment: I suggest to **NOT** have a global variable to keep the SqlConnection reference because the Connection Pooling render this approach counterproductive. Did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: @Steve. It's not clear. I re-read your sentence and I get it now. Can I suggest you edit and reword? Sorry for the overly assertive comment.

Comment: I will implement this method, thanks for the info.  I also have a few additional questions about database. I have a quite extensive form that a group of people will be filling out to submit to a database and in turn have a type of intranet that pulls that data.  What is good practice when a form submits to a database?  Only once is ideal or would multiple times be just fine? I was advised that hitting the database only once per session is best.
Also, can I use standard <input> html tags to submit in aspx or more/less ideal to use asp webforms?   What are your thoughts?    Any other pointers.

Comment: @SeanRobbins really start posting new questions, you get more attention.

Comment: @AndyBrown, updated, hope it is more clear now (well this is the most clear text that I can get out of GoogleTranslate)

Comment: Will do.  Thanks a ton folks.  I'm going to mark this as complete.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is trying to insert into a table called Table. Does that really exist? If not then put the actual table name into the query. If your table really is called Table then I strongly recommend you change it to something less confusing.

Also, stop writing commands by concatenating text **now**. Learn how to use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) in order to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

**EDIT**

An insert statement uses the format specified in the [BOL documents for INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx), and the [examples provided therein](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Table is a keyword, so don't use it as a table name. If you have to use a keyword, you need to escape it using square brackets. See [BOL: Delimited Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176027%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

I still say, don't use "Table" as the name for a table. Make your life easier.

Oh, and **write secure code** (see the above comment re SQL injection, and how [Linked In got hit](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/06/21/linkedin-slapped-with-5-million-class-action-suit-over-leaked-passwords/), and how much it cost them)

Comment: +1 for point out exact problem.. Table with name `table` is not exists.

Comment: the table in the database IS named dbo.Table

Comment: Actually I think the insert syntax is  wrong but the bigger problem is naming a table "Table" and writing insecure code

Comment: @SeanRobbins The name `Table` is one sql keyword, Change your sql as: `insert into [Table] values....` and avoid to use reserved keywords...

Comment: Changed 'insert into Table values' to 'insert into [Table] values' and all works fine.   Andy, you are the SH$T!  Thanks   Note to self, stay away from simple names.

Comment: @SeanRobbins. No problem, see my recent edit for more info. And please, review the OWASP docs, and learn why SQL injection is both [crucial to prevent](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/06/21/linkedin-slapped-with-5-million-class-action-suit-over-leaked-passwords/), and easy to avoid using Parameters. Never write insecure code again, and be more employable as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Changed 'insert into Table values' to 'insert into [Table] values' and all works fine. Thanks Note to self, stay away from simple names.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MCTX-ZAFEER\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ZKAbid_Db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa@1234");
    public int checkLogin(Ad_login ad)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_Login", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Admin_id", ad.Ad_id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", ad.Ad_Password);
        // cmd.InsertCommand.Connection = connection1;
        SqlParameter objLogin = new SqlParameter();
        objLogin.ParameterName = "@isValid";
        objLogin.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit;
        objLogin.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(objLogin);

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int res = Convert.ToInt32(objLogin.Value);
        conn.Close();
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Wherever you are using ExecuteNonQuery() you should catch SqlException or you need to throws from your function.

In the case given above `Button1_Click` is the function using ExecuteNonQuery() from SqlCommand class.

Now what happens that this function ( **ExecuteNonQuery** ) has definition to throws SqlException. so you have two option 
 - you can also throws SqlException 
 - or you can put this line in try catch block to handle the Exception.